# how protons(H+) react with matter and cause the solution to be acid?

Tags: ph, solutions, intermolecular-forces

For example if my hands were put in a HCl solution how does the protons in the solution which in high amounts will interfere/react with my hand(skin->proteins..) and cause it to burn...or how protons react with a plastic bag and cause it to melt.

Answer (score 2):

Well HCl won't desolve all plastics. In case of your hand there are complex proteins involved containing a variety of elements e.g, carbon, nitrogen, oxygen..., when your hand comes in contact of a proton, the proton is a electrophile and seeks negative charge centers, where ever on a protein it finds the negative charge center e.g, on oxygen atom in a hydroxyl(-OH) group in some amino acid in some protein in your hand, it will attach itself to the oxygen and eventually causing it(oxygen) to loose off from the protein as water, because the ion H20^+ isn't stable and the newly formed Oxygen Hydrogen bond isn't easy to break, so the part breaks off as water. millions of such reactions or even trillions happen eventually corroding off the hand or al large part of hand exposed to protons in a mobile medium. 
An acid burn isn't actually a burn but corrosion of proteins, and it doesn't either melt things away rather disintegrates them.

Comment: `it will attach itself to the oxygen and eventually causing it(oxygen) to loose off from the protein as water` Do you have a reference to support this claim? I'm no expert, but I'm not sure wether the proteins actually decompose when brought into contact with acid. I would have found it more likely that the change in pH and the accompanying protonation of hydroxyl and amino groups leads to irreversible changes in the conformation of the proteins and thus inactivates them.

Comment: The example I gave below is Alanine(An amino acid) reacting with HCl.   _________________________CH3CH(NH2)COOH + HCl -> H2O + CH3CH(NH2)COCl________________

As it's a neutralisation reaction (products must be water and a salt).

Comment: this reaction is a dehydration reaction that is the reacting molecule looses water molecule

Comment: `change in pH and the accompanying protonation of hydroxyl and amino groups leads to irreversible changes in the conformation of the proteins and thus inactivates them` -  the proteins get decomposed and a part of the protein is detached off as water molecule(in above given reaction of Alanine) which is seen eventually as the protein structure disappearing off. the protein part that still sticks to hand is eventually inactivated as its structure is no longer that of the reacting protein

Comment: also when the acid has corroded a part of skin whcih is a protective covering the sensitive proteins inside turn into [zwitterions](http://http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion) helping the reaction to occur easily.

Comment: In the above example I took [Alanine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alanine/) found on the inside of our body, a better example would have been [Arginine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arginine) in our skin, but that molecule is a bit large to be shown in the comments.

Comment: if you find an answer useful mark it as answered, it helps future users and prevents duplication of questions